# SQL Query takes 100% CPU - Maria DB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, gtfs

We have converted all the GTFS architecture to Maria DB tables.

https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/examples/gtfs-feed

So we have tables like
 - stop
 - trip
 - stop_time
 - etc

Then we have an SQL query to find all the stops after the current stop so we use the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.stop_id 
FROM   (SELECT stop_id, 
               trip_id, 
               stop_sequence 
        FROM   stop_time 
        WHERE  stop_id IN :stopIds) t1 
       inner join (SELECT stop_id, 
                          trip_id, 
                          stop_headsign, 
                          stop_sequence 
                   FROM   stop_time 
                   WHERE  trip_id IN (SELECT trip_id 
                                      FROM   stop_time 
                                      WHERE  stop_id IN :stopIds)) t2 
               ON t2.trip_id = t1.trip_id 
                  AND t2.stop_sequence > t1.stop_sequence;
```

However, when I run this query for each stop to populate it once in a different table to use the result set later, unfortunately the CPU usage goes to 100%

I am not sure why, thanks in Advance.

Comment: There's a ton of joins going on in here, so if you have a lot of records this could be crunching through billions of rows of data.

Comment: Why not provide some `sample data` and the `expected result` (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ) *Perhaps you could be using LEAD() OVER() now that you are using Mariadb*

Comment: @tadman any suggestions to optimize the query?

Comment: @Used_By_Already...will try to provide sample data

Comment: @SumitVairagar I'm not sure MySQL is the best tool for the job here. It looks like you need a more graph-oriented database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IN ( SELECT ... )`, depending on the version of MySQL/MariaDB may optimize extremely poorly (ie, CPU).  Try to turn it into a `JOIN`.

`AND t2.stop_sequence > t1.stop_sequence` smells like the worst way to do "groupwise-max".  Is that what it is part of?  It is O(N*N).  There are faster ways.  The fastest that I have found are *here*.  Depending on your requirements, it can be O(N) or better.

`FROM ( SELECT ... ) JOIN ( SELECT ... )` also may optimize terribly poorly -- neither 'derived table' has an index, so you there will be multiple table scans (ie, CPU).  Let's see `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to see if it says `All` on one of the derived tables.  To fix, consider creating one of the subqueries as a `TEMPORARY TABLE` *and* providing a suitable index.

And, as already mentioned, if you are using MariaDB 10.2, consider completely rewriting the entire query with Windowing and/or CTE techniques.